# RecyclerView Index out of bound exception

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        if (holder instanceof FooterViewHolder) {
            FooterViewHolder footerHolder = (FooterViewHolder) holder;
            footerHolder.submit.setText("Submit");
            footerHolder.submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
               @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "You clicked at Submit button", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        } else if (holder instanceof ItemViewHolder) {

            ItemViewHolder itemViewHolder = (ItemViewHolder) holder;

            questions q = quests.get(position);
            itemViewHolder.title.setText(q.getQuestion());
            int otl1 = q.getOption1();
            int otl2 = q.getOption2();
            int otl3 = q.getOption3();
            int otl4 = q.getOption4();
            char c2 = (char) otl2;
            char c3 = (char) otl3;
            char c4 = (char) otl4;
            System.out.println("OPTIONN 4 char" + c4 + "OPTION 4 INT" + otl4);
            if (c2 == 'O') {
                itemViewHolder.opt1.setText(otl1);
                itemViewHolder.opt2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                itemViewHolder.opt3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                itemViewHolder.opt4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (c3 == 'O') {
                itemViewHolder.opt1.setText(otl1);
                itemViewHolder.opt2.setText(otl2);
                itemViewHolder.opt3.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                itemViewHolder.opt4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else if (c4 == 'O') {
                itemViewHolder.opt1.setText(otl1);
                itemViewHolder.opt2.setText(otl2);
                itemViewHolder.opt3.setText(otl3);
                itemViewHolder.opt4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            } else {
                itemViewHolder.opt1.setText(otl1);
                itemViewHolder.opt2.setText(otl2);
                itemViewHolder.opt3.setText(otl3);
                itemViewHolder.opt4.setText(otl4);
            }
         /*   itemViewHolder.itemText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "You clicked at item " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }); */
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int size = quests.size();
        if (position == (size+ 1)) {
            return TYPE_FOOTER;
        }
        System.out.println("Position of card-------" + position + "------card");
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        int c = (quests.size() + 1);
        return (c);
    }
```

Getting Index out of Bound exception when trying to display the cards in my above code. number of cards(Size 8) when adding footer to display submit button(which is text view) error is displayed

Comment: Submit button which is a textview why?

Answer (score 0):

`getItemView` method's `position` param starts from 0 so no need to increase size by 1.

```
    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        int size = quests.size();
        if (position == size) {
            return TYPE_FOOTER;
        }
        System.out.println("Position of card-------" + position + "------card");
        return TYPE_ITEM;
    }
```